# Django Restframework _ update user model with special custom token?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

in DRF i have a some custom action that will do something to user model.user instances are all in state of **is_active = False**.Im trying to make something that turns the user to **is_active = True**. i made some a token model that has OneToOne to my user model.the function im trying to make is : if token that user put in the form equals to user.token then set **user.is_active = True**.im confused how to do that. I made my own serializer class :

```
class ActivateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    phonenumber = serializers.CharField()
    token = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['phonenumber','token']

    def get_token(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        x = request.data['phonenumber']
        obj = UserProfile.objects.get(phonenumber=x)
        if request.data['token'] == obj.first_token:
            obj.is_active = True
        obj.save()
```

i know this is not .create() .or update() function.so this is how I reach so far.I dont know what view i should use for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new POST endpoint in your API in order to get this custom action, for example:

`api/users/<phone number>/activate`

Then, in the view class, you can implement the action:

```
from rest_framework import status, viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route
from rest_framework.response import Response


class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    # Use your own user serializer
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['post', ])
    def activate(self, request, phonenumber):
        obj = UserProfile.objects.get(phonenumber=phonenumber)
        # The POST request expects a token
        if not request.data['token']:
            return Response({'message': 'Token not provided'},
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        # Compare the token
        elif request.data['token'] == obj.first_token:
            obj.is_active = True
            obj.save()
            return Response({'message': 'User activated'})
        # Maybe you could add an error code if you need
        return Response({'message': 'User not activated'})
```

Comment: tnx for replay .** problem is :KeyError at /api/ac/9121363777/
'token'  >> **  . i checked out and print the request.data it returns empty {}.make sense cause there is nothing comes from request yet.request is empty .

Comment: taghiss the snippet expects that you send a `token` value within the POST request, as you do in your code.